# update null to not null

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have a link if ser clicks it should update null field to not null but i am getting

> 1064 mysql error near 'delete ='NOT NULL' where ThirdPartyCategoryID=29' at line 3

This is my query

```
ALTER table thirdpartycategorymaster Modify delete char(1) NOT NULL
```

where am  i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete is a reserved word, so you need to use either brackets such as

```
update  thirdpartycategorymaster 
set     ThirdPartyCategoryName='ecommerce', 
        [delete] ='NOT NULL' 
where   ThirdPartyCategoryID=29
```

or identifier quote character backtick (“`”)

Have a look at [Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
alter table thirdpartycategorymaster 
modify column `delete` char(1) NOT NULL;
```